# Observing NSProgress

Tags: ios

I am using this code to track a changing number in NSProgress:

```
[progress addObserver:self forKeyPath:kProgressCancelledKeyPath options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];


- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
NSProgress *progress = object;
NSLog(@"PROG: %f", progress.fractionCompleted);
// Check which KVO key change has fired
if ([keyPath isEqualToString:kProgressCancelledKeyPath]) {
    // Notify the delegate that the progress was cancelled
}
else if ([keyPath isEqualToString:kProgressCompletedUnitCountKeyPath]) {
    // Notify the delegate of our progress change
    NSLog(@"PROG: %f", progress.fractionCompleted);
    if (progress.completedUnitCount == progress.totalUnitCount) {
        // Progress completed, notify delegate
        NSLog(@"PROG: %f", progress.fractionCompleted);
    }
}
}
```

This is what I get:

```
<NSProgress: phase=Loading; state=Waiting; fractionCompleted=0.000000> from peer: <MCPeerID: 0x14e1f220 DisplayName = alessandro's iPod touch-593288>
```

Noting more. I wanted to use a progress view with the fraction completed, but I don't get any value. The NSlog PROG is never called...